# is a rebase enough when the remote advance?

Tags: git

I have the following situation

```
 origin/master, master
|
some_commit
|
|  * HEAD-> thebranch, origin/thebranch
|  * some other commit
|  * some third commit
|/
* the last common commit
```

I am not planning to add any commit to `thebranch`, I am just using it.

Now I have received notice that the developer of the branch has probably rebased it to the top of master and add some commits to it

**The question**

My question is how should I proceed in this case?

**My guess**

I am thinking on doing

```
git fetch origin thebranch
```

then rebasing my local thebranch to master

and then merging it?  but this will produce a merge commit no?
I am confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not actively using that branch and not making code changes, you could simply reset your local branch to the remote and continue using it from there. This is one of the dangers of rebasing or otherwise changing the history of a remote branch, if people have it checked out, they have to somehow get back on track with the remote branch.

To do so, just fetch for the branch and reset. You don't want to make changes to the branch so merging or rebasing wouldn't make sense. You just want to move the pointer to the new commit.

```
git fetch origin thebranch # update your local copy of the remote branch
git switch thebranch       # make sure you're on your local branch
git reset origin/thebranch # resets the current branch to what's currently in origin/thebranch
```

Depending on your situation, you may need to do a hard reset by adding `--hard` to the reset command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just *using* the branch, first, I do not see the point in having a local branch for it. You would live happily ever after by just doing:

```
git checkout origin/thebranch
```

Then when the branch moves, as is the case right now, you can simply do

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/thebranch # that's right, checkout the same remote branch
```

Now, going to your question, the remote branch has moved, and you have no intentions to actually *add* anything to it, you just need your local branch to go to that spot where the remote is. Given that the branch has been rebased (or even it it hasn't been rebased, you could do the same thing):

```
git checkout thebranch # checkout local branch
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/thebranch # set local branch (index and working tree as well) in origin/thebranch
```

That should do.

Warning: `git reset --hard` cleans up whatever changes you have hanging around in index and the working tree.

Last but not least, let's not avoid the opportunity to learn something else about rebase. Your proposal to rebase your local branch on top of the remote branch is *not* a good proposal. Mainly because git would *try* to create new commits on top of the remote branch (which should not be done *unless* you know what you are doing). Let's take this example of yours:

```
* some_commit (master, origin/master) 
|
|  * blahblah (HEAD-> thebranch, origin/thebranch)
|  * some other commit
|  * some third commit
|/
* the last common commit
```

Suppose that the developer working on `origin/thebranch` decided to rebase the branch:

```
* blahblah (origin/thebranch)
* some other commit
* some third commit
* some_commit (master, origin/master) 
|
|  * blahblah (HEAD-> thebranch)
|  * some other commit
|  * some third commit
|/
* the last common commit
```

If you just ran `git rebase origin/thebranch` git would try to apply the last 3 commits that make up *local* `thebranch` **on top** of `origin/thebranch`.... which would be a waste of time if the new commits were not changed by the original developer (then git would complain about empty commits and asking you to skip them... there is no need for that, right?). Another possibility is that there might have been conflicts when the original developer rebased the branch.... do you want to deal with them creating new commits on top of their work? I don't think so, right? But, ultimately, the reason to avoid a rebase is because you can't be sure if the new commits actually resemble the old one, right? The developer might have done a completely different work in the new branch (say, a *ref%cktor*) that has no relation to the old work and you would be trying to bring over the old code... which is a **no-go**.

Comment: About that, in the branch thebranch I have added some code and data files. They are not commited or staged. do I have the risk of losing them with `git reset --hard`?

Comment: **Absolutely**. It's not a risk. It's a _certainty_ that you will lose them. If you have changes laying around, you should stash them before running `git reset --hard` , then you can stash them out. `git stash save "Coming back in a second"; git reset --hard origin/thebranch; git stash pop`

Comment: Thanks. I thought stash only saved tracked files. My files are untracked yet,

Comment: Untracked files should be fine.... unless they were added in the new branch. You should really be careful about changes laying around when doing a `git reset --hard`. There's an option to ask git to also stash untracked files.